# Accessing wildcard JSON field value in Logstash JDBC statement

Tags: json, jdbc, logstash

I am wondering if there is a way to access and get the name of a sub-field of a field in json without know its key.

Ex:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Percent_Processor_Time": 1
    },
    "name": "win_cpu",
        "tags": {
        "host": "Test",
        "instance": "_Total",
        "objectname": "Processor"
    },
    "timestamp": 1526593441
}
```

In this jdbc output:

```
jdbc {
      driver_jar_path => '${LOGSTASH_HOME}/vendor/jar/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar'
      connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://database;database    Name=test;user=test;password=test"
      statement => [ "exec stream_mss.ins_system_metrics ?, ?, ?, '', ?, ?", "[tags][host]", "@timestamp", "name", "processor.time.percent","[tags][instance]", "[fields][Percent_Processor_Time]" ]
   }
```

I want to access the json field under the "fields" json field without having to know the key of it. I want this because the input I get has a non static key for that field so I have to write separate jdbc outputs for each separate field key. Also I would want to grab the key for that field and use it.

So what my ideal jdbc output would look like.

```
   json {
        @field_name = get_field_name in "fields"
   }
   jdbc {
              driver_jar_path => '${LOGSTASH_HOME}/vendor/jar/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar'
              connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://database;database    Name=test;user=test;password=test"
              statement => [ "exec stream_mss.ins_system_metrics ?, ?, ?, '', ?, ?", "[tags][host]", "@timestamp", "name", "@field_name","[tags][instance]", "[fields][(wildcard access)]" ]
    }
```

Or something in this realm of idea.

I am open to using any of the plugins Logstash has available to solve this.

Ignore that my connection_string is not real. I omitted stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a nice way to do this I found out. I just had to hard code each possible query.